# How do I call an Object Function from an onClick Event?

Tags: javascript

I have a test.html which includes tree.js.

in this HTML I have

```
<div id='forObj'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var obj = new Tree(document.getElementById('forObj');
</script>
```

Inside the Tree.js File I have a function called

```
this.draw
...
else
            {

                    div.onclick = function(){obj.eventFoo(this.id);};

            }
```

...

my Problem is: Now everyone has to refer to the Object obj, or this will not work.

How can I generalize it, so the Object can get every name the coder wants to use?

Comment: use this.eventFoo instead of obj.eventFoo

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. You also have a missing close bracket in the first code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define your own `obj` variable with the current instance, using [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572) for the event listener:

```
… else {
    var obj = this;
    div.onclick = function(e) {
        obj.eventFoo(this.id);
    };
}
```

See also [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572) for a very similar manifestation of the problem (though you *want* to use the `this` of the handler).